# Is there a summary in Civ5 of all currently active (trade) agreements with all other civs?

Tags: civilization-5

I haven't found out yet whether there exists a (trade) agreement overview.

That is, is there some list of all active agreements or do I always have to check per other civ in its agreement history?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only the deal history you already found (Diplomacy -> Diplomacy Overview -> Deal history). The history differentiates between active and older deals, so you only have to check the list of active agreements.

Lets hope they provide some better overview with a future patch.

Comment: This seems different from Martin's way of checking per civ, since it does show all civs at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can also click "declare war" in the diplomacy screen and the game will present you with a list of current deals and trade arrangements. Just don't click "yes" after that unless you want to.